# Launch of the program when all the main is in comment

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I use Code :: Blocks but since yesterday when I put all the main in comment, the program works anyway, as if it did not compile any more.

Moreover, no matter the modification made (only in the main), the program does not change.

Comment: which is a clear signal that the compilation phase didn't happen.

Comment: I have this : `Output file is bin\Debug\XXX.exe with size 386.67 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`

Comment: Don't you try to compile in Release mode but execute the Debug compiled before?

Comment: I do not thing. The most amazing thing is that this problem happened on my own, I have been on this project for several weeks and I have not changed anything about code::blocks for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a right click on my project -> Clean then I Rebuild and it's OK !